# Stop devise from automatically creating a session after a successful registration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, session-state

I'm using STI and have 2 models inheriting from User. 
One type of User can only be created by the other user (Admins create Testers).
The problem is, every time I register a new tester with the admin, it creates a session for the tester.
Perhaps there is a documented way to do this somewhere I haven't found?  Can I stop devise from automatically starting a session when I register a new user?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple solution: DON'T include the :registerable module in the model. I have it in for Admin, out for Tester.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-after-registration-(sign-up)

This url may help.In Devise we can create custom methods to do after signup.So, in that function you can clear the session and redirect to some other page which you wanted to.

like,

```
class NewController < Devise::RegistrationsController  
  protected    

  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)  
    logout_user  
    flash[:notice[ = "You have to activate before logging in"  
    redirect_to some_special_page  
  end  
end
```

Comment: this is a great idea and has sent me down the right path, but I'm still trying to destroy the session for the tester that the admin created.  Really close though...